# Minecraft Modding Using Forge: GradleStart is in default package?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

My project runs, and I see my mod populating within Minecraft, but for some reason my code doesn't do anything. I followed a basic tutorial that should be adding an item with a texture. I also set some basic method as such within Main to test whether this is working or not:

```
  public void onPlayerTick(TickEvent.PlayerTickEvent tick)
  {
    System.out.println("testing 123");
  }
```

Upon loading of the world, this doesn't output anything.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's working now. I made the dev environment again, this time with a different tutorial from the beginning. The main difference was this tutorial used intellij like me, unlike the other tutorial which used eclipse. Seems to be working because something in the init method printed out something in the format that is expected in the console (meaning it is compiling and using the code properly). So it appears to be working... It seems. I used these tutorials, they were very in depth, would recommend regardless. This is the playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxZiPYkNuhkQKH-QlM0C_3-LvjbQA8ZAu